# HTML, CSS - Aligning Vertical Tabs To The Center

Tags: html, css

I attempted this vertical tab tutorial from W3School and I would like to apply the same method on my website. Anyhow, I can't seem to align the vertical tabs in the center of the page after decreasing the width sizes. I tried adding `div` at the beginning of the codes and tried aligning the `div` to the center but still failed to do so.

Need help on this.

```js
function openTest(evt, testName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(testName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d62929;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.li1 {
  float: left;
}

.li1 a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li1 a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c12525;
  color: white;
}

.li1.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #c12525;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d62929;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul1 li1,
  ul1 li1 {
    float: none;
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  footer {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
}

footer {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  clear: both;
  /* clearing floating affects from both left,right sides */
}

.footp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  float: inherit;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 320px;
}

.align {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1"><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown li1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Study</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mainFrame.html">Conduct Study</a>
        <a href="report.html">Reports</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li1"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Full')" id="defaultOpen">Full</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'QRC')">QRC</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Cold')">Cold</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Hot')">Hot</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Room')"> Room</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Full" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Full</h3>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul class="align">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="QRC" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>QRC</h3>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul class="align">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Cold" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Cold</h3>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul class="align">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Hot" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Hot</h3>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul class="align">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Room" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Room</h3>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul class="align">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <div>
    <footer>
      <p class="footp">&copy;All rights reserved.</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Internal Use Only</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Maintained By</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to centre? I couldn't understand from your question. The `div` with `.tab` class?

Comment: agree, question is not clear

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Yes, correct. I wanna put the whole vertical tab to the center.

Comment: @cerberus99 What about the `divs` with class `.tabcontent`

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao The whole vertical tab consist of the `.tab` and also the `.tabcontent` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involves wrapping the `divs` with class `.tab` and `.tabcontent` inside another `div` and applying `flex` to that wrapper `div`. This also requires the `.tabcontent` to have a width so as not to take the entire width of the pa

The new HTML

```
<div class="verticalTabContainer">
    <div class="tab">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="Full" class="tabcontent">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="QRC" class="tabcontent">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="Cold" class="tabcontent">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="Hot" class="tabcontent">
      ...
    </div>

    <div id="Room" class="tabcontent">
      ...
</div>
```

Additional CSS

```
.verticalTabContainer {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabcontent {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```js
function openTest(evt, testName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(testName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d62929;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.li1 {
  float: left;
}

.li1 a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li1 a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c12525;
  color: white;
}

.li1.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #c12525;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d62929;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul1 li1,
  ul1 li1 {
    float: none;
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  footer {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
}

footer {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  clear: both;
  /* clearing floating affects from both left,right sides */
}

.footp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  float: inherit;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 320px;
}

.align {
  display: inline-block;
}

.verticalTabContainer {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabcontent {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1"><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown li1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Study</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mainFrame.html">Conduct Study</a>
        <a href="report.html">Reports</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li1"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <div class="verticalTabContainer">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Full')" id="defaultOpen">Full</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'QRC')">QRC</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Cold')">Cold</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Hot')">Hot</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Room')"> Room</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Full" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Full</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
      <ul class="align">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="QRC" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>QRC</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
      <ul class="align">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Cold" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Cold</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
      <ul class="align">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Hot" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Hot</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
      <ul class="align">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Room" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Room</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
      <ul class="align">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <div>
    <footer>
      <p class="footp">&copy;All rights reserved.</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Internal Use Only</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Maintained By</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: I suggest instead of "abusing" `<br>`, you should use the `margin` and `padding` attributes to `align` or `position` your elements. Also if possible, give up on floats and swith to a completely to `flexbox`

Comment: Thank you so so much for the feedback and surely will follow as advised. Your codes worked perfectly as how I wanted. Thanks again ! :)